# How can I search a specific field of a specific document in firestore using Algolia ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, algolia

In My database, I have a collection named 'Friends'. Inside this collection, each document represents a user. and let's say for user1, I have a field named 'friends' which is an array that contains userIDs of the friends that user1 has. In this form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQoJM.png)

I followed this way instead of creating a sub-collection and represent each user by a document because I think this is more efficient in terms of documents reads when retrieving friends.

I am fine displaying friends of each user, but my problem is with implementing the Algolia search.
I have used Algolia search for searching all users but 'User' collection is different because each user is represented by a document on its own.

Thus the main question is what should I do in index.js or in the flutter code to enable full-text search using Algolia so that each user can search his list of friends for a specific name ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating documents with firestore id , use name or any other known data of the user as document id so that u can easily access that document